# Tableviews "slide down" when tapped in Widget 2.0

Tags: coronasdk

With Widget 2.0 if tapping tableviews, they "slide down" and disappear almost off-screen, and on a second tap they slide back to their original position.

This seems like some sort of "layer dismissal" functionality, but why would they suddenly appear on tableviews?

Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

There were serious bugs when they realeased Widget 2.0. Tableviews are implemented using scrollview which still contain a lot of bugs. I already submited 2 bugs but it will take some time until they will fix them. Try to install the latest corona build and check the forum or try to submit this bug.